# Tourism/survival sentences in most languages

Tags: data-request, language, dictionary

I am looking for the first 50 or 100 sentences/words that an English-only-speaking tourist would learn when staying in a non-English-speaking country for a few weeks.

For instance, the first few words would probably be translations of "Hello" and "Thanks" then maybe numbers and survival sentences like "Where are the toilets?", then maybe transportation/time/colours/local food.

Requirements:

- Must have the **word in local script**, the English **meaning**, and **pronunciation** in either IPA or English such as `asah-lomu ah-lay-koom` or both.
- Must be freely reusable, as I intend to transform this data into [flashcards](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/) and redistribute them (freely under the same license)
- At least 30 languages, the more the better.